# npm installation not working under Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, node.js, npm

I just tried to install `node` and `npm` on Debian Stretch. I installed node like decribed [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

After installing `nodejs-legacy` too I got the `node` command working but `npm` command still won't be found.

So, I tried to install it manually via `apt-get install npm` but it just tells me that it can't find the package. Next I tried the "Fancy Install (Unix)" from [npm repository](https://github.com/npm/npm) which fails with

```
    install npm@latest
fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.5.1.tgz
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.1272/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
added 1 package and removed 1 package in 0.45s
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/bin/npx -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.5.1
updated 1 package in 1.21s
It worked
```

Although it creates the link for the `npm` command the links are broken.
Does anyone an idea how I can get `npm` running?

One more thing: 
I have the visual studio code repositories in my sources.list which uses node too. Is it possible that that's a reason why it downloads a node package without npm when I do `apt-get install -y nodejs`?

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: You could try downloading and compiling the source manually:  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/

I know that NPM is included in those packages from at least v6 and later.

Additionally, I am using NVM on osx to manage versions but it also has install capability...maybe you could try installing via nvm and seeing if that fixes your issue.
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why my tries from above did not work but for me installing `nvm` like described [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md#install-script) and then performing `nvm install node` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if it *should* be available in the `npm` package but there's a [problem](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/npm):

```
Error: Package not available in this suite
```

I read somewhere that it's deliberately not available because there are so many outstanding security issues (with the packaged version).  I solved my problem without any "sudo run this script from the Internet" solutions like this:

```
cd /tmp/
wget  https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
view  setup_8.x
echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x  stretch  main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
wget -qO - https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
apt update
apt install  nodejs
```

`npm` is installed as part of that `nodejs` package.

Comment: Yes that was a part of my problem, any idea how to circumvent that without nvm (which worked for me)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error about the missing `read-package-json.js` by using the latest install script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npm/npm/latest/scripts/install.sh. (Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18524#issuecomment-385369514).

After that you might run into an error about missing `rimraf`. At least for this there is a Debian Stretch package: `apt install node-rimraf`. For alternatives, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18524 and https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19105.

Finally, you might run into an error about missing `make` if you don't have that installed yet, so `apt install make`.